# Having trouble with the loop in this sub. Trying to highlight a column

Tags: excel, vba

All I'm trying to do is loop through all values in column "D", and if that cell ends with an "A", highlight it.

Don't understand the simple error I'm making with the loop, thanks for any input.

```
Sub test()

    Dim x as Range 
        
     With Worksheets("1") 
      
                For Each x In Range("D2:D").End(xlUp).row
                    If x.Value Like "*A" Then 
                    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                    End If
                Next x
            End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you think that you can use ActiveCell.Interior.  Its more likely that you need 'x.cells(1,1).Range.Interior.COlor=vbRed' or some close derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Some fixes:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim x as Range 

    With Worksheets("1") 
        For Each x In .Range("D2:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            If x.Value Like "*A" Then 
                x.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
         Next x
    End With
End Sub
```